# Timer implementation for string input on android

Tags: android, arrays, string, timer

I have a string that gets a value from a counter. I want to display the previous counter totals in a text view. I have this part working, however what I do not understand how to do is give a small time for input before displaying it in the string. I think what I want can be better described through a visual example. The counter starts at a value of 20. The example will be if the user wants to add a total of 3 to the counter, making the final value 23. The buttons only allow the user to input -1, +1, -5, and +5.

what I have now, when the user hits +5, -1, -1 to increase the counter to 23 it displays as follows
20(+5) *This value clears when the -1 is pressed
24(-1) *This value clears when the -1 is pressed
23(-1) *This is the final value displayed.

While it gets the 23 the counter displays, I would like the final output to be 
23(+3)

I am assuming a timer would be needed to allow the user press multiple buttons before showing the values but I am not sure that is the case. The code I have so far for the string values is

```
           add1p2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter1 += 1;
            updateLifeP2();

            // add the click history for p2
            btnPressedTVP2.setText(tmText + "\n" + 
                            String.valueOf(counter1));

        }
    });
```

Comment: Why not just use [Android's NumberPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html)?

Comment: I have not heard of that, what exactly does that do?